# Best practice for serving modal windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I am showing modal alert messages, the same message will appear on multiple pages. I don't want to have to maintain `<div id="modal">contents</div>` on all of those pages. Can anybody recommend how, possibly with JS, I can serve my  code to multiple pages? Or am I stuck with inserting the code into each one? Ideas?

Comment: What JS code (or library) are you using to display the modal alerts?  Different ones have different methods of doing this.

Comment: Realy depends what the contents are. Are they dynamic or the same throughout. The easiest and laziest option is an iframe. But if you have dynamic content, you could pull the content through an ajax call. If the contents really aren't substantial, you should just insert them directly into your page.

Comment: I am using this: http://accessibility.oit.ncsu.edu/training/aria/modal-window/ with JQuery library.

Comment: Contents are static...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put contents to your main JavaScript file, and call it from there.
Example when you have your `all.js` file which is included in all your pages, add this into that file:

```
var modalContents = '<div id="modal">contents</div>';
```

And when calling modal alert, load `modalContents` variable into it.

Comment: call it with document.write()?

Comment: Yep for example. Or jQuery $("#idOfYourModalContent").html(modalContents);